# Opportunity StageName from Closed Won to Closed Cancelled

Tags: opportunity, validation, validation-rule

Got an error condition formula below:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( StageName ), "Closed Won"),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( StageName ), "Closed Won"),
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( StageName ), "Commit")
    ),
    NOT( ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Closed-Cancelled"))
)
```

Closed Won cannot be revert back to any stages except "Closed-Cancelled". What could be possibly wrong with the condition above?

Answer (score 0):

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( StageName ), "Closed Won"), 
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed - Cancelled")) 
)
```

Comment: Could you add some useful description?